# SDL 2.0.3 with Ogre 1.9.0 and IOS

Tags: c++, ios, sdl-2, ogre

I am trying to integrate SDL 2.0.3 to work Ogre 1.9.0 for window and events handling, it works fine under Linux but I am having issues under IOS 7.1.

I cannot get any input or window events from SDL. I am using the `wmInfo.info.uikit.window` to get the handle and then I pass it to Ogre. The only thing I am not sure is if I am getting the GL context properly. I can get only one event when I start SDL with Ogre `SDL_APP_DIDENTERFOREGROUND`. Is there anything special I need to do for the IOS.

I would really appreciate any help as I am stuck on the problems above.

Also I am working under OSX and IOS 7.1 simulator. Below are my changes to the original Ogre iOS template.

*SDL and Ogre initialization:*

```
//SDL
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
{
    printf("Could not initialize SDL\n");
    return 1;
}
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_EGL, 1);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_ES);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 2);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 0);

SDL_DisplayMode displayMode;
SDL_GetDesktopDisplayMode(0, &displayMode);

/* create window and renderer */
SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow(NULL, 0, 0, displayMode.w, displayMode.h,    SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

SDL_GLContext glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

SDL_SysWMinfo wmInfo;
SDL_VERSION(&wmInfo.version);
SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(window,&wmInfo);

m_pLog = Ogre::LogManager::getSingleton().createLog("OgreLogfile.log", true, true, false);
m_pLog->setDebugOutputEnabled(true);

String pluginsPath;
m_pRoot = new Ogre::Root(pluginsPath, Ogre::macBundlePath() + "/ogre.cfg");
m_StaticPluginLoader.load();

m_pRenderWnd = m_pRoot->initialise(false, wndTitle);

size_t winHandle = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(wmInfo.info.uikit.window);
size_t glHandle = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(glContext);

Ogre::NameValuePairList params;
params["externalWindowHandle"] = Ogre::StringConverter::toString((unsigned long)winHandle);
params["externalGLContext"] =   Ogre::StringConverter::toString((unsigned long)glHandle);
params["externalGLControl"] = String("True");

m_pRenderWnd = m_pRoot->createRenderWindow("", displayMode.w/2, displayMode.h/2, false,  &params);
```

*My main loop:*

```
DemoApp demo;
demo.startDemo();

bool done = false;

SDL_Event event;

double mStartTime;
double mLastFrameTime;

while (!done)
{

  mStartTime = OgreFramework::getSingletonPtr()->m_pTimer->getMillisecondsCPU();
  OgreFramework::getSingletonPtr()->updateOgre(mLastFrameTime);
  OgreFramework::getSingletonPtr()->m_pRoot->renderOneFrame();
  mLastFrameTime = OgreFramework::getSingletonPtr()->m_pTimer->getMillisecondsCPU() - mStartTime;


    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case SDL_FINGERMOTION:
                SDL_Log("Finger Motion");
                break;

            case SDL_FINGERDOWN:
                SDL_Log("Finger Down");
                break;

            case SDL_FINGERUP:
                SDL_Log("Finger Up");
                break;

            case SDL_QUIT:
                done = true;
                break;

            case SDL_APP_DIDENTERFOREGROUND:
                SDL_Log("SDL_APP_DIDENTERFOREGROUND");
                break;

            case SDL_APP_DIDENTERBACKGROUND:
                SDL_Log("SDL_APP_DIDENTERBACKGROUND");
                break;

            case SDL_APP_LOWMEMORY:
                SDL_Log("SDL_APP_LOWMEMORY");
                break;

            case SDL_APP_TERMINATING:
                SDL_Log("SDL_APP_TERMINATING");
                break;

            case SDL_APP_WILLENTERBACKGROUND:
                SDL_Log("SDL_APP_WILLENTERBACKGROUND");
                break;

            case SDL_APP_WILLENTERFOREGROUND:
                SDL_Log("SDL_APP_WILLENTERFOREGROUND");
                break;

            case SDL_WINDOWEVENT:
            {
                switch (event.window.event)
                {

                    case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED:
                    {
                        SDL_Log("Window %d resized to %dx%d", event.window.windowID, event.window.data1, event.window.data2);

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This might help as a guide: [Setting up Ogre3D with SDL2 and CEGUI](http://digiorgi.info/233/setup-ogre3d-with-sdl2-cegui/)

Comment: Yeah I saw this one but it doesn't work under IOS or OSX .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize this question is a few years old now, but I had the same problem and I hope my solution is of some use to others.

The problem is that you are replacing SDL's UIView (SDL_uikitview) with Ogre's UIView (OgreEAGL2View) and so you are no longer going to receive any touch input or any of the features implemented via SDL_uikitviewcontroller or SDL_uikitview. This replacement is taking place inside the GLES2 RenderSystem (specifically in OgreEAGL2Window.mm)

The way I solved this for myself is to create my own UIViewController and UIView, and then put that view *behind* SDL's view. You can then receive touch input from SDL's view, while rendering into Ogre's view. This will require creating an Objective-C compilation unit and the code would look something like:

```
#include "OgreEAGL2View.h"
#import <UIKit/UIWindow.h>
#import <UIKit/UIDevice.h>
// other includes

// call this from your C++ framework
// pass it your startup params
void setupMyiOSViews(Ogre::NameValuePairList &params)
{
    // grab the UIWindow (you must have called SDL_createwindow before calling this)
    SDL_SysWMinfo wmInfo;
    SDL_Window *sdlWindow;
    SDL_VERSION(&wmInfo.version);
    SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(sdlWindow, &wmInfo);
    UIWindow *w = wmInfo.info.uikit.window;

    // get a rectangle with the screen dimensions
    CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    // instantiate a view controller of Ogre's subclass of UIViewController
    EAGL2ViewController *myViewController = [[EAGL2ViewController alloc] init];
    // instantiate a view of Ogre's subclass of UIView
    EAGL2View *myView = [[EAGL2View alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    // make sure it's not transparent
    myView.opaque = YES;
    // attach the view to the viewcontroller
    myViewController.view = myView;
    // add the view to the current window
    [w addSubview:myView];
    // put the view *behind* the SDL view
    [w sendSubviewToBack:myView];

    // add the window, viewcontroller, and view to the proper parameters
    // UIWindow maps to param: externalWindowHandle
    // UIViewController maps to param: externalViewControllerHandle
    // UIView maps to param: externalViewHandle
    Ogre::String str_w = Ogre::StringConverter::toString((unsigned long)w);
    Ogre::String str_vc = Ogre::StringConverter::toString((unsigned long)myViewController);
    Ogre::String str_v = Ogre::StringConverter::toString((unsigned long)myView);

    params["externalWindowHandle"] = str_w;
    params["externalViewControllerHandle"] = str_vc;
    params["externalViewHandle"] = str_v;

    Ogre::LogManager::getSingleton().logMessage("externalWindowHandle: " + str_w);
    Ogre::LogManager::getSingleton().logMessage("externalViewControllerHandle: " + str_vc);
    Ogre::LogManager::getSingleton().logMessage("externalViewHandle: " + str_v);

// now pass params into Ogre::Root::createRenderWindow
}
```

Note that there is no need to even create and context with SDL. Ogre will now be rendering into it's own view and viewcontroller